# Windows 8.1 triple monitors - can't enable all 3 at the same time

Tags: multiple-monitors, graphics-card, hdmi, dvi, windows-8.1

Today decided to update from Win8 Pro to Win8.1.

Everything was fine with enabled 3 monitors (Extended mode, not Eyefinity) at the same time. But after update can't enable 3d monitor, only 2 could be enabled at the same time.

Did current things before write question here:

- Remove all drivers, reboots, re-installs
- Different cable input's and orders of enabling
- Tried to enable each monitor from Catalyst and Windows Screen Resolution

Spec's:

- Windows 8.1 Pro
- XFX HD7970
- 3 of LG E2442

Cables:

- 2 DVI
- 1 HDMI

Googled for many time and found one of possible solution is to buy ACTIVE mini DisplayPort to DVI/HDMI, but maybe there are some another more simple solutions?

Comment: This is taken from AMD Website: Use of 3 or more displays with AMD Eyefinity technology requires a DisplayPort-capable panel or an AMD Eyefinity validated dongle. See http://www.amd.com/EyefinityDongles for a list of validated DisplayPort dongles. Ref: http://www.amd.com/us/products/desktop/graphics/7000/7970/Pages/radeon-7970.aspx

Have you got the new Windows 8.1 Driver?

Comment: Yes, I installed last driver from ati.com and even tried beta driver - same problem...

Comment: Does Windows Screen Resolution "Detect" button detect a 3rd monitor? Does Catalyst detects existence of the 3rd monitor? (and just not displaying anything)

Comment: Yes it does - http://i.imgur.com/hiR9Jdi.png

Comment: I'm having a similar problem, except now after 8.1 upgrade my 3rd monitor running on display port doesn't show in windows at all.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Before buying miniDP to DVI adapter, I tested with Ubuntu booted from USB and, as was expected - it worked even without AMD drivers, all 3 monitors, like a charm.

So, seems that Windows 8.1 changed some configs and now it try to autoconfig only Eyefinity mode, even if it's disabled, or something...

Also, report this bug to Microsoft would be nice :)

P.S. Problem resolved with miniDP to DVI adapter. Final cable set is:

- DVI
- DVI
- ACTIVE mini Display Port to DVI adapter

Update: [Solution 2] Also works without mini Display Port, just unplug your GPU from Motherboard for some time and then re-plug it and all monitors.