# Can't enable third monitor after upgrading from Win8 to 8.1

Tags: windows-8, multiple-monitors

I recently updated to Win 8.1 - now only 2 of my 3 monitors are working, after they were all working perfectly fine under Win 8.

I have 3 x HP E231's running on an AMD R9 280x - One of the monitors is DVI, the other two are Mini-Display Port to DVI.

In Screen Resolution or the Catalyst Control Center, every time I try to enable the third monitor it tells me I have to disable another one.. I can't find much info on the net about this problem - have checked here [Windows 8.1 triple monitors - can't enable all 3 at the same time](https://superuser.com/questions/662695/windows-8-1-triple-monitors-cant-enable-all-3-at-the-same-time) but the guy just brought an adapter - I know all three monitors were working under Win8 so why not 8.1?

Cheers

Comment: I suspect the driver has been updated... Are you using the AMD drivers or the W8 drivers?

Comment: Are you running the current drive release?  The driver display model changed significantly in order to support Direct X 11.1.  I have found that in most cases Windows 8 drivers in general DO NOT WORK on Windows 8.1.

Comment: I ended up just rolling back to vanilla windows 8 after getting heaps frustrated with it, so I'm sorry, I can't make this as answered.. if anyone else has been in the same boat, chip in with your comments.

As it is, I can't be bothered upgrading to 8.1 again, even though AMD has now brought out a later set of drivers. Their support is just too terrible to bother.

Answer (score 1):

I added more 1 solution, which is:

Also works without mini Display Port, just unplug your GPU from Motherboard for some time and then re-plug it and all monitors.

[Windows 8.1 triple monitors - can't enable all 3 at the same time](https://superuser.com/questions/662695/windows-8-1-triple-monitors-cant-enable-all-3-at-the-same-time?lq=1)