# Only two screens can be active at the same time

Tags: multiple-monitors, windows-8.1, hdmi, displayport, display-adapter

I'm having the problem that only 2 monitors seem to work simultaneously. Right now I have these monitors:

- **Samsung SyncMaster S24B350** (VGA to DVI adapter)
- **Samsung SyncMaster P2450H**  (DVI to DVI)
- **Iiyama E2483HS** (HDMI to DP cable)

and this setup:

- Sapphire R9 270X
- Windows 8.1
- Latest drivers (according to AMD driver autodetect)

The Iiyama one is the one I'm trying to add to the setup. However it only works when I remove another screen.

When I look at my config this is the view I get (the not detected display is the onboard VGA adapter):

[image]

When I try to change it to 'extend desktop to this display', I get the "*The display settings could not be saved. Please try a different combination of display settings.*" message.

In [my](https://superuser.com/questions/678276/cant-enable-third-monitor-after-upgrading-from-win8-to-8-1) [search](https://superuser.com/questions/662695/windows-8-1-triple-monitors-cant-enable-all-3-at-the-same-time) [for](http://arstechnica.com/civis/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=1228483) [an](http://www.tomshardware.co.uk/answers/id-1686451/raedon-7979-run-displays-windows.html) [answer](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_8-hardware/after-a-clean-install-of-windows-8-i-cannot-get/f700820a-8781-47a1-be62-6f545927d4dc) I have come across the statement that I need an *active* HDMI to DP adapter.

This is the cable I have:

[image]

Am I correct in assuming this is a *passive* one and that this is where the issue is located?

If not: what suggestions do you have to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To use more than 2 screens on an AMD card, at least one screen must use a (true) DisplayPort connection. Your cable is indeed a passive adapter (utilizing the HDMI fallback mode on DP+). As such, this is not a true DisplayPort connection.

Active adapters (or "converters") are usually advertised as such. Unfortunately, there are quite some low-quality products on the market that may not work. I suggest to go by Amazon ratings to improve your chances of finding a good one. [This one](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00DOZHLAA) looks decent enough.

Also, take note of the different plug sizes. Due to Apple's use of Mini-DisplayPort, these are the most common adapters.

Comment: I have ordered an active adapter and will receive it monday, I'll get back to you to let you know how the situation is then.

Comment: After I plugged in the HDMI cable together with the active HDMI-to-DP adapter I didn't get any vision and both my pre-existing screens restarted every 10 seconds. What could cause this?

Comment: Which adapter did you buy? Feel free to link to your local store.

Comment: http://www.computerstore.be/product/330946/club-3d-displayport-naar-hdmi.html

Comment: Unfortunately this adapter, expensive as it may be, appears to be passive. The DP++ logo also hints at this. The store does not have any active adapters on sale.

Comment: Geez. Alright, I guess I'll be sending that one back. Considering Amazon's one-month delivery times I'll accept (and award bounty) to your answer in a few days; I'll get back to this once I've received it.

Comment: Received my active adapter a few minutes ago: plugged it in, detected all displays in the screen resolution config window, activated the new desktop and rearranged it a little. Works perfectly now. Thanks a lot for the constant followup help!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you have already seen this before, but an answer from justanswer might be useful for you:

> When using mini DisplayPort-to-singlelink DVI adapters, quad output is divided into two pairs (displays 1 and 2, and displays 3 and 4). The displays used in each pair must be identical (with the same manufacturer and model number) and must be identically configured (with the same resolution)...

[Source](http://www.justanswer.com/computer/5sarg-can-t-windows-accept-third-monitor.html) - Post by Shauqat about half way down the page.

Comment: I'm using a (normal) DP to HDMI adapter so it's not entirely the same.  I don't know for what types of adapters this applies though but I'll keep it in mind.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried connecting one screen to the on-board graphics?
Not the best option for gaming, but if performance isn't paramount, and your main goal is just having three monitors, it might be worth a try.
There may be a setting change to be made in the BIOS to (re)enable the on-board graphics.

I've done such a thing on windows 7 and had 4 monitors running, 2 from an AMD HD6850, and 2 from the Intel integrated graphics.

As far as the active vs passive adapters, there's this page:
http://support.amd.com/en-us/recommended/eyefinity-adapters