# 6870 Wont Accept 3 Monitors?

Tags: display, graphics-card, multiple-monitors

I have a XFX Radeon HD 6870, and I am using a DVI I to VGA, HDMI to DVI D, and a mini display port to HDMI and only 2 displays work. I have tried all combinations with them.

Answer (score 2):

Your DisplayPort to HDMI adapter is not “active” (as in with actual conversion). As such, the connection the graphics card sees is not DisplayPort, but HDMI. You need an active adapter. They are surprisingly hard to find, though.

I’ve answered a similar question earlier and will provide a link to it soon. **Update**: [Here](https://superuser.com/a/720320/219095)’s the answer I mentioned. Unfortunately, the OP didn’t report on the working adapter.